# curl is unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: curl, lets-encrypt

I'm using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificate and even though when I'm accessing server with a browser, browser reports page is being "secure", however I'm getting following when I use `curl` instead.

```
# curl https://X.X.X
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
#
```

My system:

```
# cat /etc/debian_version 
8.7
# cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was only using `privkey.pem` & `cert.pem` as my fqdn.pem, and now daisy chain `fullchain.pem` as well.

fix:

```
# cat privkey.pem cert.pem fullchain.pem > ~/fqdn.pem
#
```

`curl`:

```
# curl -I https://X.X.X
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.11.12
Date: Mon, 03 Apr 2017 16:56:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 196
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=""

#
```